# Java IOException while trying to copy inputstream to outputstream

Tags: java, exception, inputstream, ioexception, outputstream

I'am trying to write the inputstream image to OutputStream to display the image in the browser this is the code:

```java
try
{
    InputStream input = Filer.readImage("images/test.jpg");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        responseBody.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

the readImage:

```java
public static InputStream readImage(String file) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {

        return input;
    }
}
```

but I get an error while writing:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The try-with-resources closes the stream when you exit the block

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
```

ie. when your method returns.

Just remove it and take care of closing the stream at the end of your other method body.

As stated in the comments, [here's a link to the official tutorial on `try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: The [link to the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) would be nice to have in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) the resource is closed when the statement completes:

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.
>
> Prior to Java SE 7, you can use a finally block to ensure that a resource is closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly. The following example uses a finally block instead of a try-with-resources statement: